# Am I misusing the "Very Low Quality" flag?

Tags: discussion, flags, low-quality-posts

I'm a little confused about what the "Very Low Quality" flag is supposed to be used for. I've read these answers about the VLQ flag:

- [Is the Very Low Quality flag too ambiguous?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93595/is-the-very-low-quality-flag-too-ambiguous/93606#93606)
- [Why were these “Very low quality” flags declined?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/189373)

Which state that the VLQ flag is intended for those questions which should basically be deleted ASAP. Makes sense to me.

However, after recently having a VLQ flag declined and taking some time to think about why the flag was declined, I realized that I had been using the VLQ flag as a notification that a question should be *closed* ASAP, in addition to its original purpose as a notification that something should be deleted.

So given the Meta answers above, I have been misusing the VLQ flag, and my apologies for that. But considering the options available to people in the VLQ queue (namely, closing for questions or deleting for answers), there seems to be a bit of a contradiction here.

The VLQ flag is supposed to be meant for things that should be deleted. However, for questions, the only option available to reviewers in the VLQ queue is just to *close* a question flagged as VLQ. Thus, if you flag a question as VLQ, you're far more likely to have something simply closed, without someone with delete powers ever seeing the question, which I don't think matches up well with the stated purpose of the VLQ flag as given in the Meta answers above.

It is because I knew that reviewers in the VLQ queue have a close option for questions instead of a delete option that I started using the VLQ flag as a close flag in addition to its original purpose. Am I the only one to think like this, and so am I wholly incorrect in this behavior?

In addition, if VLQ is supposed to be for questions that should be deleted *immediately*, why is *closing* the question the only option (ignoring edits because editing VLQ questions is rather pointless) available to reviewers in the VLQ queue? Is that behavior intended, and/or should it be changed?

Comment: As a side note, I'm a little curious about how the flag made it out of the VLQ queue, and whether the question should actually have been considered VLQ, but I feel that that's just me trying to rationalize having a flag declined. Perhaps I just need to step back and recalibrate what "Very Low Quality" means...

Comment: No, you’re right; [VLQ flags on questions are useless](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195673/it-shouldn-t-be-possible-to-flag-questions-as-very-low-quality).

Comment: @false Ah, I wasn't aware that this had been covered already. Guess that's a flag I'm going to have to stop using... Thanks!

Comment: I stopped using that flag once I realised that it never got approved as useful. It was an experimental decision. If "the rule" is not to use it, then maybe it should be deleted.

Comment: @DanielDaranas Strangely enough, out of the probably hundreds of VLQ flags I have (ab)used, that was literally the first one that was declined. Pretty much all the rest were marked helpful from closes or edits. I agree though; something should be done about it.

Comment: @DanielDaranas weird. 4/5 of my low quality flags were deemed helpful

Comment: @Andreas Actually, I have bad memory. I checked and 75% of my 28 Very Low Quality flags were deemed helpful. Since for _other_ flags this percentage is 94%, though, I tend to avoid the relatively more frequent disputed/declined outcome of the Very Low Quality flags, and I have practically stopped using them.

Comment: @DanielDaranas i would assume that confirms OP's claim that it's too vague. i usually use it when it's phrased in an english appearing like the person started using english 2 weeks ago or apparently didn't even bother to form a comprehensible question. I wasn't aware it's a flag for deletion requests (Though most questions i flagged with it are deleted now)

Comment: Sounds like VLQ has nothing to do with quality

Answer (score 68, accepted):

**Use VLQ for obvious, unarguable *garbage*.**

Regardless of whether or not it ends up in /review or the mod queue (and most of the time, it'll end up in *both* at least for a little while...) VLQ flags on questions that should be *closed* just create unnecessary overhead - someone else has to spend more time thinking about *why* the question needs to be closed because you didn't specify.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'm convinced now that I was wrong, and will start reforming my behavior; hopefully this question reaches anyone else who had been (perhaps unintentionally) abusing the VLQ flag. There's just one last question which I neglected to state outright (and I updated the question to add it): Since VLQ is supposed to be used for content that is essentially harming the site, why is the only option available to reviewers to just close questions? Was that intended?

Comment: It's not, @user3580294 - there's also an edit button, and moderators get a really handy Delete button... For most reviewers though, closing is the only option they *have* for out-and-out garbage - it doesn't really matter what they close it *as*, so long as it gets closed the system will generally handle the deletion automatically after 9 days.

Comment: I kind of glossed over the edit button because I thought that editing a VLQ post is pointless, but in any case, rest of it makes sense. I completely forgot that the roomba existed, so I suppose that takes care of the missing delete for normal users, as well as the rest of my questions. Thanks for taking the time to answer!

Comment: Old post, but a mod recently sent me to this answer in declining a VLQ that I had flagged.  Reading this and the OP made the decline very clear to me.  This was very helpful and appreciated - suggestion for mods to link to this in their decline message if they don't already do so.

Comment: I got declined with a link to this -- I flagged as VLQ because I wasn't sure of the exact close reason I should use and I figured other people would be able to figure it out. I'm slightly annoyed that nothing was done about it, but I just ended up flagging as no MCVE, so something should be done about it.

Comment: Garbage posts aren't being accepted as VLQ. If it's not about quality then don't offer a quality radio button

Comment: @HashRocketSyntax none of the questions you flagged with VLQ were garbage. Off topic != garbage. Example you flagged: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57936907/how-can-i-use-input-in-jupyter that’s perfectly readable English, not garbage.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It's just an ambiguous tag and it's clearly causing problems. As a product manager and SO power user, please trust me when I say that this is an easy fix that you want to make. The fact that a user had to make this original post to bring this problem to the team's attention in the first place means that the team is either out of touch or not looking at measurements of the flags + the fact that the the team is defending the source of the problem after the fact signals that they are even more out of touch. Listen to the feedback and adjust.

Comment: @HashRocketSyntax you really don’t have to tell me that. I’m no SO developer so I can’t do anything about the flag anyway. My views on the flag align quite well with Cody here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357344.

Comment: @MartijnPieters with all of your rep I figured you were an SO founder!

Answer (score 26):

I am feeling the way you do, whenever a question is really just garbage, I tend to prefer the low-quality flag for a broader audience.

Yesterday I marked the question [Using Web Sources in WP8 apps [on hold]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24725003/using-web-sources-in-wp8-apps) as low quality and it got declined, but closed as too broad.

The message I got was

> declined - Please use close flags. VLQ flags should only be used for things that warrant immediate deletion.

Now that said, the question was not good and it is deleted by now, so I am not really sure any more of when to use the VLQ flag.

Another problem might be questions that fulfil multiple criteria for closing them.

Comment: Hmmm, it's rather odd that your flag got declined when the question was deleted anyways... Perhaps the question was deleted by high-rep users instead of a mod? Maybe the question was considered bad enough for deletion but not bad enough for *immediate* deletion, but in any case, I agree, it's pretty unclear when to use VLQ when different people have different ideas on what is VLQ...

Comment: As for multiple closing criteria, I think it's been mentioned on Meta that the *exact* closing reason doesn't matter too much, as long as the question is closed. I don't always agree with that, but depending on the question sometimes just getting it closed is the priority...

Comment: If you can get reasonable results using existing voting/community-moderation, I think that is favorable over involving a moderator.  If there is a close vote reason that applies, use that.  If we all used flags instead of close votes, there wouldn't be enough moderation resources to go around to deal with them all.  Usually flagging is for the exceptional cases that can't be dealt with using any of the other tools given to us.

Comment: @AaronLS I suppose the thing here is that I flagged knowing that they would almost certainly be dealt with by the community instead of the moderator because they would end in the VLQ queue. So in a way, I was "getting reasonable results using existing community moderation". Now that I have seen the light, though, I agree with you -- flags should be used for exceptional cases only. Unfortunately, the way things are set up at the moment it doesn't seem that the system is designed for flagging being the exceptional case for VLQ questions (at least for people like me who misused flags)...