# How should I handle gibberish answers?

Tags: discussion, flags, answers

I just came across this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30259272/369450) in the low quality review queue:

> hh fgbfdhbfghgfhngfnj safsdfhn kljhn fjkhnb fjhbn fjkhn dsfjkhbn vfduji ujhiuf juihbnf juhbn fvbjuihnbfc jbki ufu g juig fvhg

I voted to deleted it with no comment necessary, and down voted it. Are those the appropriate steps? My first instinct is to go the question, and flag the gibberish answer as "spam". However, the flag description suggests to me that it's only for promotional answers.

> Exists only to promote a product or service, does not disclose the author's affiliation.

1. How should gibberish answers be handled within a review queue?
2. What if I find an answer like this while browsing the site outside of a review queue? Is it "spam", "not an answer", "very low quality", or just down-vote worthy?

Comment: ["Use VLQ for obvious, unarguable garbage."](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265764/839601)

Comment: Flagging as not an answer or very low quality then vote to delete and downvote are all good options. If you notice a user doing this often then you could flag for mod attention and explain. Though, if this is something that's happening constantly by the same user then the community and system are likely to spot it and take care of it.

Comment: That answer makes complete sense to me.  I'm not sure what your issue is.

Comment: This reminds me of the "question" yesterday about buying an alligator.

Comment: There was a question about buying an alligator? Now I want to see that.

Comment: It's not the worst answer by any means.  The ones that are understandable, but suck hugely, are far more dangerous.

Comment: @MrTheWalrus - It was deleted pretty quickly, as well as the account that posted it.

Comment: Was it this one? http://goo.gl/gGlnOH

Comment: Reminds me of this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/30lcX.png

Comment: This might well be from the same [source](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251415/179541), those gibberish speaking idiots trying to troll the site. But, I can be wrong...

Comment: @JamesWilkins: A php green crocodile makes sense, because you can't be both a python and a crocodile, or be ruby and green at the same time. (Unless maybe that time is 25 December.) But an alligator? That's just stupid.

Comment: This wasn't the case this time, but if there's an edit history, and you have the rep to see it, it may be worth checking. Sometimes new users overwrite their bad answers with garbage instead of deleting them, and it's nice (although obviously not mandatory) to explain to them why they shouldn't do that (it makes the site even less useful, and gets them even more downvotes, than if they did nothing…).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It does not qualify as "spam". Flag as "not an answer" and downvote. Those who have the power to cast delete votes should vote to delete.

Comment: I will say that I often accept spam flags on these, because gibberish posts sometimes are precursors to full-on spam. Spammers probe the posting system using these, and create throwaway accounts for them. It can be helpful to destroy these accounts to get the anti-spam system working on them early.

Comment: Downvotes cost rep points, and flags don't. It seems slightly vexing to expend your rep on something you don't even disagree with, but on pure, contentless noise.

Comment: @9000 The reputation cost of the downvote is refunded to you after the post is deleted, and you can be *certain* that gibberish posts *are* going to be deleted.

Comment: @BradLarson I have to disagree with that approach because I think it misleads users in thinking that spam is more than it actually is on SO. Every now and then we get people confused about the scope of spam. They flagged something that was not in fact spam and come to meta to complain. Granted that gibberish *could* be from a spammer testing the waters or it could be a user's younger sibling that got a hold of the user's laptop, or a user who is just damn angry at the world. The latter two are definitely *not* spam.

Comment: It look like this is the right course with the exception that gibberish answers should be flagged as "very low quality" according to Shog9 in [Am I misusing the “Very Low Quality” flag?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265573/am-i-misusing-the-very-low-quality-flag/265764#265764).

Answer (score 15):

When you encounter an answer like this in the Low Quality Posts review queue, you should select **Recommend Deletion** -> **No comment needed**.

When you encounter an answer like this while browsing the site, you should flag it as **not an answer**.

Comment: _"No comment needed"_ You could always provide something insightful and relevant, like "23ljjbq2hwsWEY2whsnjwU#$I#%&3uhrsnj".

Comment: Og ichi plof. Ti ra nesi!