# Gibberish Answer - Why was this declined?

Tags: discussion

I flagged this post as "Not An Answer":

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41196355/2912011

and it was declined, I'm trying to understand why. According to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294394/how-should-i-handle-gibberish-answers) it should be flagged this way. I am fluent in VBA and for the life of me I cannot understand what is being communicated in this post...

Was my flag in error, and if so why?

Comment: It looks like it's just a poorly formatted answer to me, but an actual attempt to answer. There's code, if you click "edit" you'll see they _tried_ (and failed) to format the answer. Edit: And someone else has edited now to format it correctly.

Comment: @Kendra ahh I see just needed formatting :) thanks, much more intelligible now, still not sure if this is an "answer" per say, but at least it looks better

Comment: I formatted the code as it's supposed to be formatted. So now we can discuss about it being a real answer or not.

Comment: @Floern So yeah, its definitely an attempt, but I'm not sure it's an "answer", doesn't this qualify under [VLQ](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265573/am-i-misusing-the-very-low-quality-flag/265764#265764) or am I missing something?

Comment: i mean, it may be low quality, but i wouldn't exactly consider it VLQ.

Comment: It was not an answer, it was an attempt to edit to fix the bug in his prior post.  Quite a lost puppy of course.  Moderators don't take the time to discover this.  Well, who does.  You might have a bit more luck if you flag "Very Low Quality", albeit that the VLQ queue is not doing very well either.  Very hard to get trash cleaned-up these days, there is way too much of it.  I voted to delete both posts, with some luck that will happen.