# Not an answer - disputed flag

Tags: discussion, flags, disputed-flags

I flagged this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44961/what-are-the-primary-differences-between-haskell-and-f/45031#45031 because I believe this should be a comment to the question. But my flag was disputed.

So, I'm bringing the question here to understand more about it. Why was that disputed? I would like to know the reason so as not to flag these type of answers again.

Also, is there a way I can see the actual review of this question, like how many people declined it?

Answer (score 20):

Here's the answer for reference in case it get's deleted for some reason.

> F# is part of the ML family of languages and is very close to OCaml. You may want to read this discussion on the [differences between Haskell and OCaml.](http://www.oreillynet.com/mac/blog/2006/03/haskell_vs_ocamlwhich_do_you_p.html)

#### Flags should not be used for posts that don't require moderator intervention

This is an attempt to answer the question. It may not the best attempt ever made to answer a question, but it definitely isn't the worst attempt either. This does not qualify for the "Not an Answer" flag in the first place, it may qualify for downvotes (currently sitting at 37 upvotes and no downvotes) and delete votes if users that have that privilege feel that it should be deleted, but it shouldn't be flagged.

On another note, this didn't make it to a moderator queue, where it most likely would have been declined. Instead it was handled in the community [Low Quality Posts Review Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/10662537), where the majority of users (3) disagreed that it should have been flagged. This saved the moderators the time required to review and decline your flag, and it saved you from a declined flag.

Disputed flags don't count against you, it just means the community disagreed.

Too many declined flags in a short period of time will end up in a flag ban.

### Related

- [When to flag an answer as "not an answer"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265552)
- [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370)

Comment: Interesting, now I understand why I had [2 declined flags on this copy-paste-code-only answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15009157/1326147), first flagged as *not an answer* and later as *very low quality*: it's too bad even for moderator intervention.

Comment: While I understand the reasoning here, I think the real problem is with the name "not an answer" being too ambiguous. Taken literally, almost nothing qualifies as "not an answer" literally (except in the most extreme cases of a non-responsive "answer"). I believe that because of that, many people consider "not an answer" to mean "not an answer to the question that was asked" which does appear to be the case here... the post seems to me to be a comment and not an answer to the question that was asked, so "not an answer" seems reasonable even though it's not.

Comment: @Armfoot That is an attempt to answer the question, and it doesn't have severe content or formatting problems. It could be improved by the community or by the author, so it definitely doesn't warrant a VLQ flag. If an answer isn't useful it should be downvoted, and if you have delete votes, then vote to delete it. Flags should not be used as a substitute for delete votes. See [my answer here for more info on the VLQ flag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/314731/4639281).

Comment: @mah While I understand your frustration, the NaA flag has a lot of useful information on when it should be used, please read the referenced posts in my answer. Flags should not be used as super-downvotes or delete-votes. There are lots of answers that come in every day that should be flagged, but not every horrible answer warrants flags. Moderators are very busy, and should not be bothered with trivial matters that can be handled by the community.

Comment: @TinyGiant It's a link-only answer, though I guess a reviewer without domain knowledge might not think so. Classifying one language doesn't count as specifying the difference between two languages.

Comment: @JanDvorak It isn't a link only answer, as without the link it is still an attempt to answer the question. Not only that but the relevant information at the end of the link *could* be edited into the answer with correct attribution. Flags should not be used as super-downvotes or delete-votes. Please read the referenced posts in my answer.

Comment: Good thing I've long given up on caring about the site quality then, I guess...

Comment: @JanDvorak It's not that it necessarily shouldn't be deleted or improved, I'm not arguing that point, it's that it doesn't warrant moderator attention. It can be handled by the community using the tools available to us. This is especially important with upvoted or accepted answers as moderators deletion votes are unilateral. Community deletion votes require multiple users to agree on the matter, not just two users working in collusion.

Comment: What tools do you have in mind? The NAA flag pushes stuff to the LQ queue. Isn't that the desired course of action?

Comment: @JanDvorak The NaA and VLQ flags push posts to moderator queues, when flagging as such you're asking for a moderator to delete the content, and there's no real way of knowing whether a post will end up in front of a moderator or not, as such you should operator under the assumption that the flag goes straight to the moderator queue. The LQPRQ is an extra abstraction that allows users to vote on whether or not an answer warrants moderator attention or not. The tools available to you are editing, voting, and voting for deletion.

Comment: @JanDvorak [See my answer here for more on this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/314731/4639281)

Comment: @TinyGiant based on the reasoning you're providing here (taken at face value, I have not read the refs you linked), I still feel "not an answer" is a bad name. I'm not disagreeing with the reasons for not bothering mods, I just think "not an answer" is probably never a reason to bother mods. Rather, a reason mods should get involved should be in the flag naming, such as "offensive spam and I'm not able to edit". As long as the flag name is generic, it's going to be misunderstood. The more specific the name of the flag, the less likely it will be to become misused.

Comment: @mah If it isn't actually an **attempt** to answer any question conceivably asked on Stack Overflow (it doesn't even have to attempt to answer the question asked, as long as it is an attempt to answer a question that could be asked on Stack Overflow), and it would be a waste of time to wait for users with delete votes to take notice and vote to delete, and it should just be nuked from orbit as soon as humanly possible, then and only then should you flag as Not an Answer. I'm not going to go in depth with examples here because those are provided on the referenced posts quite adequately.

Comment: @TinyGiant So in this specific case, _Q: What's the difference between a and b? A: a is a widget_ how is that answer considered an answer? The question did not ask what either a or b is but the "answer" only states what a is. This is descriptive of the question/answer in this post, is it not? I suppose the comparison of a to c, and a link to discussion of c vs b is relevant here, but in general it's a crappy answer and the number of upvotes it received is evidence that a picture of a ham sandwich could get upvotes too :-)

Comment: @mah It is an **attempt** to answer the question, if it is wrong or not useful, downvote it and, if you have the privilege, vote to delete it. Again, please read the referenced posts in my answer for examples and a more in-depth explanation. Also see: [A minor change to the description of the “not an answer” flag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286229/a-minor-change-to-the-description-of-the-not-an-answer-flag) and the first answer there.

Comment: Something that may be worth adding to your answer here: if you follow the "strip the markup" rule of thumb, this answer still contains a speck of useful information: that the differences between Haskell and OCaml may provide some insight and that discussions of that nature exist. That would be a very *bad* answer on its own (and should be downvoted to oblivion), but it's an attempt to answer, as you say.

Answer (score 4):

So, the whole question was deleted... it happened what should happen. BTW, if you see a problematic answer, check the question... if it's problematic *too* act on the question and forget the answer.

Comment: Strongly disagree. The question was already closed. That should be enough to discourage similar questions. The question was from back in 2008 when such questions were okay, was interesting, and got useful answers. That should have been reason enough to keep it around. It would have been so much better to [lock it as historical](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for) instead instead of making it inaccessible to most of the community. By the criteria in there though, it at least needs to be undeleted first to quality.

Comment: @hvd well, I strongly disagree.

Answer (score -5):

An answer can be wrong, unhelpful, guesswork, dangerous, boring, brief, or any number of undesirable things, but that doesn't mean it's NAA. Let's look at a hypothetical question of "How do I print on the console?".

Wrong, but not NAA:

> Print with the `calculate_derivative()` function.

A guess, but not NAA:

> I'm new here, and I don't know this language, but maybe it's `print()`? Try that one out. If it doesn't work, send me a private message.

Unhelpful, but not NAA:

> Printing to the console is so passé. Create a GUI instead like this: (GUI code)

Dangerous, but not NAA:

> Use `print()` and then call this command to immediately reformat your hard drive: (dangerous code)

Most people would leave this as a comment, but it isn't NAA:

> `print('this is so annoying why do i have to have a minimum number of characters this answer is perfectly fine')`

Adds nothing, but not NAA:

> As the accepted answer says, use `print()`.

Plagiarism, but not NAA:

> (detailed answer on how to print, obviously stolen from earlier answer)

"Thanks," but not NAA:

> You guys are absolutely right: looks like it's `print()`. That works great! Thanks for answering my question, everyone!

This is a link-only answer, but it isn't NAA:

> (link to documentation on `print()` function)

A virus, but not NAA:

> You can print with this simple library (link to virus)

This is a sarcastic joke, but it isn't NAA:

> Get some extension cords, set up your computer in your car, put the printer on the center console, and print. Make sure there's paper in the printer, or it won't work.

This is a little disconcerting (and also wrong), but it isn't NAA:

> To print, you must first hail Cthulu, the dark keeper of souls, and beg him to feast upon your computer's bits. Hail unto Him!

This is troubleshooting, but it isn't NAA:

> Do you have a monitor? Connect an output device to your machine, power it on, then use your language of choice to send output to it.

Now, here are some examples of NAA.

> kla;jerfklgthjw89e34yut89230kl2o389wydx89

> jklsfje;kl sorry my cat stepped on the keyboard

> i liek potatoz,,,,,,,,,,,,,

> testing testing, does this work?

> do you have dry skin? purchase our moisturizer here! (link to infinite popups)

Ha! That last one was a trick <del>question</del> answer: it's both spam and NAA. For that one, I'd recommend not flagging at all, in order to avoid your flag getting declined because you picked the wrong category, and declines can delay the removal of content. Don't worry - someone else will take care of it eventually.

The safest course of action is to forget about flags and simply downvote content you find unhelpful.

Comment: Totally disagree with your last point: If an answer is spam, flag it as spam. Are you scared that your flag will get declined? If it's the correct one, of course not. And always flag a post which needs to be flagged.