# Homework question without actual question and meaningless title

Tags: discussion

I came across this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35691742/outside-or-inside-for-while-loops which I flagged as very low quality which was declined.

I think I understand why it was declined as very low quality seems to be the same as 'please delete'.

I think there are a couple of problems with the question.

For example the title is meaningless, I tried to come up with a proper title but I could not think of anything.

Also the question just shows some code and asks how to fix it without clearly explaining the problem.

I believe only people who have done the same assignment can properly answer the question.

My question is how should this question be flagged?

Comment: Downvote, may be flag as _unclear_.

Comment: I would flag it as unclear if I were under 3k reputation.

Comment: After editing it, the question doesn't necessarily seem unclear. What *is* unclear (to me) was the OP marking an answer as "accepted", one which doesn't actually produce results the OP was looking for.

Comment: Why is my question downvoted here? I spend a long time looking for existing advice on how to deal with such questions but could not find anything useful.

Comment: @CubeJockey: no offence, but your edit did not make it more clear. It still is a 'here is my code, please fix it' question without actual programming related question in it. And you are making assumptions on what the OP wants because that really isn't clear.

Comment: What is wrong if someone asks a homework question. The same homework question can be applied in real world

Comment: @OmariOmosa my issue with the question is not that is homework. Actually it is not even about this specific question, it merely serves as an example.

Comment: A VLQ flag is, at this point, completely meaningless: [How do VLQ flags work, what's their relationship to the LQP queue, what's their purpose?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/314679) The bar is set so high that nothing that qualifies also fails to qualify for some other categorization.

Comment: Meta effect: this post now has a score of *-19*...

Comment: Ok, I still don't know what to do with such questions. I've stumbled onto another and it really is 'here is my homework code, what is wrong with it' with a clear question 'please fix' so flagging as unclear does not seem to fit... Maybe I should start ignore those. But the thing is, I used to find good answers on SO easily. Now I have to wade to a huge amount of crap and incorrectly accepted answers until I find something useful.

Answer (score 20):

Read the Very Low Quality flag as:

> Unsalvageable by editing

Which [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35691742/outside-or-inside-for-while-loops) apparently wasn't.

I don't know what to tell you about which flag to use.  [A series of unfortunate events](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0339291/) has rendered Stack Overflow a "fix my broken code" site, for which highly-specific homework assignments seem uniquely qualified.

If you feel the question is unclear, closing or flagging as "Unclear What you are Asking" seems like a suitable arrangement.

Comment: off-topic: Netflix is producing an [ASOUE](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4834206/?ref_=fn_al_tt_2) series starring NPH, due out August of 2016.

Comment: You know you've made it when the initials of your name actually result in a successful Google search.

Comment: [Off topic questions have to be cleared out of the way, but NOT via closure](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251897/839601)