# How do you strike a balance between flagging "low quality answer" and having your flags rejected?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, flags, review-audits, low-quality-posts

This morning when I tried to review posts, I've got a notice that many of my recent flags were rejected. I assumed that code-only answers or one-liners should be marked as low-quality.

Examples of rejected low quality flags:

- [jQuery-validating start time and end time selected using time picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14052432/jquery-validating-start-time-and-end-time-selected-using-time-picker/40904591#40904591)
- [Getting bad request (#400) on Ajax calls using Yii 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27126050/yii2-getting-bad-request-400-on-ajax-calls/40902652#40902652)
- [Hello, World! program for React Native throws "Could not parse the simulator list output" on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39810470/hello-world-program-for-react-native-throw-could-not-parse-the-simulator-list-o/40901275#40901275)

OK, I start reviewing and I see a decent answer with good code that the author just didn't bother to describe:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/14470753

I review it as "No action needed" and I get promptly banned.

How do you guys strike a balance? Or should I just flag everything by default and ignore my rejected flag stats?

Comment: @PatrickHofman Most sites don't have code-only answers, and the handling of that is somewhat nuanced.

Comment: So some sites do, so this is not a SO specific issue. @NathanTuggy

Comment: @PatrickHofman That doesn't make it terribly suitable for MSE, any more than EL&U/ELL's shared [word-request] endemic is something that should really be hashed out here. If it's something *some* sites have in common, they can cross-reference between their metas; MSE is for when *lots of different* sites have the same problem.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: (And, in fact, the closest thing ELL in particular has to code-only answers, [zero-explanation answers](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/3294/should-we-delete-answers-that-have-no-explanations), are handled differently than SO handles code-only, so I really don't think this is a useful general topic.)

Comment: None of those should have been flagged.  They warranted a comment or a downvote.  That review smells bad.  A diamond mod deleted it, which may be why it was included as an audit.  The answer may have been flagged for plagiarism, but I have no idea why he deleted it.

Comment: The VLQ flag [has been meaningless for a long time](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/314679/603977).

Comment: Suggest you retitle this **"Inconsistent handling of code-only answers or one-liners"**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Am I misusing the "Very Low Quality" flag?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265573/am-i-misusing-the-very-low-quality-flag)

Comment: @SurajJain that question is about the VLQ on *questions*, this is mainly about the VLQ flag on *answers*.

Comment: @Glorfindel Oh Ok

Answer (score 31):

When you're flagging something as "very low quality", you're asking for it to be immediately deleted by either community members in review or moderators. In general, for answers this is typically used for unintelligible answers or link-based answers with nothing in them beyond a link.

It's not to be used for wrong answers, short answers, or answers that only partially answer a question.

On Stack Overflow, an answer consisting of just code is generally not considered worthy of deletion just because of that. [Your first flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14052432/jquery-validating-start-time-and-end-time-selected-using-time-picker/40904591#40904591) was declined for that reason, but if you notice, that answer was copied character-for-character from the other answer left in January. Had you flagged to point that out, it would have been deleted. I've deleted that answer as a result.

Likewise, your second flag was declined for that reason, and the third answer you flagged may have been short but it was still an attempt at answering the question.

Stack Overflow (and other sites like it) walk a line between getting people an answer quickly and providing sufficient detail to make an answer complete. On the one hand, we regularly edit out unnecessary information, "thanks", and the like from answers. On the other, we like for there to be enough detail to understand why an answer is a good one. Sometimes people are a little too terse, including just providing the necessary code, and sometimes too verbose.

Those are not reasons for summary deletion, so "very low quality" generally doesn't apply as a flag type for them. I'd generally reserve those flags for gibberish, incoherent answers or for answers that couldn't stand on their own if you removed a link (and even there, I'm not wild about flagging answers of that type that have shown value).

Comment: "It's not to be used for wrong answers" - that should really be made more apparent in the flag description. The flag description just says "severe formatting or content problems", and wrongness is definitely a severe content problem.

Comment: @user2357112: no wrongness isn't VLQ in general, because it indicates at least that the answerer has some understanding of the topic and seems to be attempting to give a bona-fide answer. But sure let's improve the VLQ flag text to *"... Don't use this for merely incorrect answers"*

Answer (score 10):

> How do you guys strike a balance?

Some posts are low quality, because they are just a code dump, etc. That however is not a *very* low quality post what warrants a flag. VLQ posts are gibberish, unreadable mess, editing does not help. Those posts you mention could have one or two sentences added to them, which won't make them LQ any more. They are salvageable. Only flag posts that can't be helped.

> Or should I just flag everything by default and ignore my rejected flag stats?

Definitely not. Flags should only be used for cases that really warrant that. Flagging 'everything' will get you flag banned for a long time. Flagging will take precious moderator or reviewer time, so don't just go flag everything. Sometimes you have to skip one if you are really in doubt. That's okay.

For what the review audit is concerned. That was a post that was repeatedly posted by the same user and manually removed by a moderator (without notice). I don't really know why the moderator would remove both answers, the code seems to be related to the question asked, but I am not an expert. Sometimes review audits are just bad and you have to take a miss. That isn't too bad if you have a good record otherwise.

Answer (score 8):

So, as others have pointed out, you shouldn't be flagging answers as VLQ just because you think they aren't adequately explained; VLQ flags are for answers that are completely devoid of any content at all.  But just because these answers don't merit a VLQ flag doesn't mean that you should take no action when you come across them in the first posts queue.

The first posts queue isn't just a queue where you flag delete-worthy content for deletion or do nothing.  It's where you take any actions that may be appropriate for that post.  If the post merits deletion for being a non-answer, then yes, flag it, but if it's just a low quality answer that lacks an explanation, downvote it, to indicate that it's not a quality answer, comment on the post to explain why the answer is not a good answer, edit the post to improve presentation problems, remove noise, improve its clarity, etc.  You should also be on the lookout for red flags for other types of problematic content that would merit a flag, such as, as was the case here, a user duplicating content, spam, offensive content, or any other suspicious activity that a moderator may need to look into.

You should only be selecting "no action needed" when there really is nothing at all that you can do to improve that post, help the author understand how to use the site better, provide any feedback on the quality of the post, or *anything* else.  While that will happen, odds are you should have *something* to contribute for a good portion of posts, even (or, honestly, especially) when it's helping to turn an okay answer into a very good answer.

Answer (score 7):

I think that code-only answers or one-liners are of low quality but the flag name is [Very Low Quality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93595/is-the-very-low-quality-flag-too-ambiguous).

Consequently, I think that answers like the ones you describe should be addressed via downvoting, commenting and/or editing rather than flagging.