# What does VLQ actually mean?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

I recently flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19350124/uitableview-section-header-how-to-change-text/41827269#41827269) as very low quality:

> ```
> -(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
> {        if (section == 0)
>           {
>                 lbl.text = @"abc";
>           }
>         if (section == 2)
>           {
>                 lbl.text = @"2ndsectionbeigns";
>           }
> return headerview;
>
> }
> ```

as to me at least (given that I haven't got a huge understanding of the question) it did not provide enough context to explain **why** the answer was an appropriate answer, and what made said answer right.  As far as I was concerned it was just a block of code that may/may not have answered the question.  This flag was then declined for the reason:

> flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an
>   altogether wrong answer.

Which I originally believed to be of very low quality, however having read [this explanation for it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340802/very-low-quality-flag-declined-on-an-answer-that-was-both-very-low-quality-and-t), I feel that the person declining the flag was justified in doing so as it was just LQ, rather than VLQ.

Which leads me to my question:  Is there a definitive definition of what constitutes VLQ on SO?  I couldn't find anything in the time that I searched on MetaSO.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It's pretty subjective. The usual answer is something along the lines of "unsalvageable garbage" - so not just bad, but almost *offensively* bad, and extremely unlikely to improve.

The problem with flagging "code dumps" is that determining their merits generally requires a reasonable familiarity with the technologies involved; they're definitely not *ideal*, but sometimes a snippet is exactly what the asker (and other readers) wants, and the answer will suffice.

They still get deleted on occasion, either in response to flags or by 20K users who can vote to delete downvoted answers. The latter is probably ideal, as it involves voters with a non-trivial amount of experience.

In the case of your example, I would probably just downvote.

#### See also: [How do you strike a balance between flagging "low quality answer" and having your flags rejected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338887/how-do-you-strike-a-balance-between-flagging-low-quality-answer-and-having-you)

Comment: Also, since the answer in OP's example is probably not totally useless (as VLQ would typically be, I'd imagine), a polite comment (perhaps along with a downvote) on how to improve and explain the answer would help.

Comment: More relevantly, even if a code dump isn't useful *as is*, it's typically salvageable.

Comment: Improving the example answer here would mean totally rewriting it. It's just this side of gibberish.

Comment: Well, there's where 20K users come in, @Josh. I don't know enough iOS to differentiate between a reasonable approach and a half-assed rip of the accepted answer here; I'd guess a couple of mods on SO probably do, but if those weren't the mods who saw the flag (or if it ended up in review in front of non-iOS reviewers)...

Comment: Yup, yup, was more responding to DangerZone's point ("probably not totally useless"), sorry.

Answer (score 18):

> As far as I was concerned it was just a block of code that may/may not have answered the question.

If you're not sure, then don't use a flag. A VLQ flag is for when a post definitely needs to be deleted. That answer looks like it might reasonably answer the question, even if it does lack an explanation. You can't expect moderators to be expert enough in every programming language to be able to make that determination.

If I did see a code-only answer that I was sure *doesn't* answer the question being asked, I'd use a custom flag explaining that rather than using a VLQ flag.