# Fine tuning the low quality auto flags

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, low-quality-posts, quality-filter

I'm probably misquoting someone but it's said that *"the best moderation is the one that doesn't have to be done"*. This opinion is usually held in SE and demonstrated trough the quality filter. We reject code-only questions, try to guess if a question has improperly formated code, reject answers that are barely more than a link, reject titles which are written in ALL-CAPS, etc.

Yet, while reviewing the low quality review queue (LQRQ) I find that several post in need some help, normally by writing an explanation, which could be adverted before being posted to be more useful and that help could be automated. Right now, posts with a very low text to code ratio are fed to the LQRQ in [hopes that someone might be able to edit them into shape,](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190218/213575) the thing is, that most of the reviewers are [ill equipped to do such task](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/342192/792066) and the [system doesn't make sure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/254145/213575) that the best able reviewers are shown these post in need of help. I suggest a change, before allowing these post into the system, show a warning (tip?) inviting the user to improve these answers, something like:

> While this answer might solve the question, the best answers are those that explain the whys and hows the issue gets solved. Please, expand your answer with an explanation of the solution.

And if the warning is ignored (ratio before =< ratio after), raise the auto flag.

Comment: I think the quote you're referring to is "The best general is the one that never fights", from the Sun Tzu. (Because battle is the most expensive solution, the general tries to achieve their goals otherwise; and similiarly this proposal tries to avoid the costly usage of human review).

Comment: @S.L.Barth Now I have an [earworm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earworm). “[I will win but never fight / That's the Art of War](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KHLW9yw4j2c)” (via [LyricsMode](http://www.lyricsmode.com/lyrics/s/sabaton/the_art_of_war.html))