# Why was a VLQ flag declined on an answer which responded to a question on V8JS with a recommendation to use PhantomJS?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, low-quality-posts, specific-answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48139979/2370483

The OP is not asking for a resource, nor does the answer offer anything beyond describing the link. He responded he was going to add something but never did. Is there something I'm missing here?

Note: I am not asking for a VLQ definition so this isn't a dupe. The other Meta also deals with a code dump. Between that and [the other VLQ guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563) this seemed to be qualifying for deletion

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does VLQ actually mean?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342191/what-does-vlq-actually-mean)

Comment: @RobertColumbia Not really. Not asking for a definition, nor was this a code block without explanation.

Comment: I also had a NAA flag declined on that post.  The non-mods reviewing the post somewhat agreed.

Comment: @francescalus That one makes sense to me. If the question is "How do I do X?", "You ask how to do X to achieve Y. To achieve Y, it's better not to do X, but to do Z instead, like so: ..." is generally valid, as far as I know, and the answer we're talking about here looks like a low-quality (possibly even wrong) answer of this type to me.

Comment: [Assuming @hvd means "declining NAA flag makes sense".] I read the question as "I tried to do X, but I get these symptoms when Y'ing, showing it didn't work".  In that context "Do Z [and you don't get symptoms when Y'ing]" strikes me as NAA, especially when the [...] isn't given.

Comment: If you ask me, the issue is that not everyone has the same definition of "VLQ". Some people would flag this as VLQ, and others would say that this post should be downvoted in stead. I would probably flag it as well, since the question is not "which tool should I use to solve this", but how to solve a specific error. Mentioning that tool XYZ could solve that problem is great, but doesn't answer the question, and requires clicking that link to find out how tool XYZ solves that problem.

Comment: They should just use jQuery.

Comment: It would have helped if the question were better.  It's open to interpretation as to what information is sought: *how do I resolve these errors?* is what I would go with, but I guess *how can I install a headless JS engine?* is a somewhat-plausible alternative.  But that does not mean that answers should get extra leeway.  Myself, I would have voted to accept the VLQ flag.

Comment: I'm confused. Recommending a different technology is typically considered a valid answer, especially if it solves the problem. The OP hasn't articulated any particular reason why they're married to V8. I agree the answer could stand improvement, but that just warrants editing (maybe downvoting), not deleting. If PhantomJS is easier to set up and can also serve as a JS runtime like V8 does, how is the answer invalid?

Comment: @jpmc26 Haven't had time to address the broader issue in another Meta, but the reason I flagged it is the answer could be summed up as `Hey, use this library instead! [link]`. There was no attempt to explain what the library does or how it answers the question. That leaves us with just the name of a library and a link. That really doesn't answer the question. Even a sentence or two would make it passable. Put another way, under the theory that any link to a library is acceptable, I could just [tell the OP to use jQuery](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The standard spiel we're usually given is that NAA flags should only be used when a moderator *without any detailed knowledge about the technologies being used* and *without seeing the question* should be able to determine that the answer is not an answer.

Additionally VLQ is [a de facto alias of NAA](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314679/how-do-vlq-flags-work-whats-their-relationship-to-the-lqp-queue-whats-their#comment294607_314734), since no mods or members of staff have ever managed to articulate an example of a post that warrants a VLQ flag but not a NAA flag and the system handles them identically.

The answer in question read:

> Use phantom instead. Easy to use. Just add phantomjs.exe in the folder where your php is executed. http://phantomjs.org/

Is it conceivable, in principle, to a person without detailed knowledge of the technologies involved, that there exists *some* programming problem that could be resolved by swapping to PhantomJS, and that this can be achieved simply by adding `phantomjs.exe` to the folder containing your PHP scripts? Yes, it is perfectly conceivable. Therefore VLQ doesn't apply here.

(I agree that this state of affairs is stupid.)

Comment: IMO the stupidity is compounded by the fact that on review, one of the reasons for _"recommend deletion"_ is being _"link only (and not spam)"_, but raising a flag of NAA on a "link only answer" is a recipe for failure if the answer is upvoted and requires mod intervention.

Comment: @yivi Yes, it's an oft-commented-on absurdity that the official standards for mods handling VLQ and NAA flags versus *users* handling those flags from review queues are totally different from each other. The underlying *rules* for whether such a flag is appropriate exist in a state of quantum certainty, unknowable at the time that the flag is raised and determined only when it is handled. That's patently idiotic, but there appears to be no official will to do anything about it.

Comment: What's weird is that this appears to be the opposite problem. I have no idea if phantomjs will answer the question. With nothing but a couple of sentences that do nothing more than say `Install this`, it looks like [any potential answer is in another castle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

Comment: "No fluffy kitten has ever complained to me that using this piece of software instead has failed."

Comment: @francescalus I'm sure your comment contains some profound wit or wisdom, but either I haven't had enough coffee today or else my riddle-solving skills just aren't good enough to figure it out.

Comment: @Machavity "Read this blog post" is an "answer in another castle"; "use this tool" is not, IMO. It's usually a *partial* answer at best, and usually a bad one, but doesn't usually warrant deletion. And *sometimes* "install this* is basically a complete answer to a question - e.g. if the Q is "Why does my build fail with error X?" and the answer is "Install `lib_some_annoying_dependency.h` with `apt`." Technical knowledge is sometimes required to distinguish the two - as is the case here. And, since answers that require technical knowledge to evaluate shouldn't be NAA-flagged...

Comment: Er, it doesn't...  I hadn't put the point to my _reductio ad fluffies_ before surprise tram arrival.  I didn't mean to post the comment unfinished.  However: is there more information in the real answer than the one I give?  If we talk about thresholds of "honest attempt to answer" is it obvious that my answer isn't but that other is, especially with "How do I get X to work?"/"Use Y"?

Comment: I'd agree with you that it is an answer to "Why does my build fail with error X?", but the question is "My build fails with error X, showing I haven't installed Y correctly; how _do_ I install Y?".  That can't be answered by "Install Z", can it?  [I haven't relevant technical knowledge.]

Comment: @MarkAmery I see your point, and I suppose that really does answer my question here, even if it does raise a deeper issue on the subject. But that's for a separate Meta post. Thanks for the answer

Comment: @MarkAmery remember that being "link only" is just *one* of the reasons why an answer could be deleted. According to the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) there are at least 6 possible reasons, but the main point is that if you "do not fundamentally answer the question", it may be deleted. The specific reason why it's considered to not answer the question, is just guidance on what kind of answers we do not accept. Personally, any answer that doesn't reach a level of quality while answering the question should be either edited or deleted.

Comment: @Braiam There is a difference between saying something may be deleted (which means that users who have the power to delete the thing may delete it and that includes users with delete votes _as well as_ through mod deletion and community review) and saying that something should be flagged. Conflating content that should be left to those with delete votes to curate with content that requires moderator intervention or can be dealt with by generalized community review is not helpful.

Comment: The point being, get to 20K and start casting delete votes. Don't use flags for purposes they can not and should not serve. The reason that it is required that you get 20K before you can start casting delete votes on other users answers is that it builds an expectation that you have some skin in the game, i.e. you shouldn't be able to cause damage without first having invested in the system and building an expected level of trust.

Comment: @TinyGiant Please, quote where I mentioned flags?

Comment: This whole question and answer are discussing flags. That is the topic of discussion here. It is reasonable to assume based on the corrective nature of your comment, that you were correcting this answer on what is appropriate to be flagged. If that is not the intended nature of your comment then it is misleading. If your comment is not relevant to the discussion, why did you post it? @Braiam

Comment: @TinyGiant *""Read this blog post" is an "answer in another castle"; "use this tool" is not, IMO. It's usually a partial answer at best, and usually a bad one, but doesn't usually warrant deletion"* This is the comment I'm referencing. Why my attempt to set a comment straight has to be put in the same category as everyone discussing the topic at large?

Comment: @Braiam Well you made no effort to convey that you were addressing that one particular ambiguity, which I read as meaning warranting deletion within the context of flagging (due to the topic of the discussion). I understand the point you're trying to make but find it rather pedantic and irrelevant to the discussion at hand.