# Low-quality questions

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts

I flagged a question for, IMHO, being of "very low quality", and got the answer:

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to
>   support it

---

As a note, this were my first ever "Very low quality" flag, in 6 years.

---

I saw somewhere saying;

- *VLQ* should be used when you *"cannot interpret content out of the post"*.

Also, in [a linked post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338890/5260024) within an answer below, it states;

- *"unintelligible answers"* (and I assume it goes for questions too)

Given these two bullets, could someone please let me know, if below sample is not a *very low quality* post, **what is?**, so I from now on don't flag *"non-low quality"* posts.

---

*Btw, I did vote to close as well, and the shown downvote is mine!, ...and the upvoter's must be in need of a badge or something.*

---

[image: post sample]

Comment: Close it as "unclear what you are asking" ?

Comment: Recommend reading: [What does VLQ actually mean?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342191/what-does-vlq-actually-mean)

Comment: @JonasWilms That I did, and it were, and now deleted by OP. Still, I would like to know what a VLQ looks like, as the one I show here obviously weren't.

Comment: related https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239688/why-can-questions-be-flagged-but-not-closed-for-very-low-quality

Comment: I really like the edit you've made. It really made it way friendlier and open-minded.

Comment: VLQ is not a super-closevote. See VLQ as a *nuclear option* instead, for when a post just needs to be deleted ASAP but isn’t spam or rude and abusive. Asking to convert a table to C# is not something that needs deleting ASAP, it just needs closing. Someone posting the results of headbanging their keyboard would be, because that’s just garbage, it will never be edited into a proper question.

Comment: For questions, VLQ is just a "I don't know what to do with this" flag. Questions flagged with VLQ go into the [Triage review queue](//stackoverflow.com/review/triage) where other users are asked to do any of vote/flag for closure ("Unsalvageable"), indicate that it needs editing ("Requires Editing"), or is OK ("Looks OK"). Selecting "Unsalvageable" results in the question going to the Close Vote queue, due to close votes/flags. A "Requires Editing" result puts it in the [Help and Improvement queue](//stackoverflow.com/review/helper). So, it's better to just vote to close or directly edit.

Answer (score 11):

The asker is making an honest attempt to get help, so this *is a question*. It is *about programming*. It's just *off-topic* though.

Ask yourself: Do you really need a moderator to step in here?
In such a case, just vote to close as *unclear* (as you did) and move on.

The VLQ flag is for unidentifyable garbage as [explained by a moderator here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338890/5260024).

Comment: @Clive Nope, I am not upset, just disappointing that SO allow such bad quality posts. And this is far from the only one I downvoted/Voted to close lately, it became a lot worse since I became a member, and hopefully it will be a nice break, thanks, and not the end.

Comment: @LGSon I disagree with almost everything you said and I believe that the votes on your question could be because of how you communicate but I don't want to make this personal. The only part I want to reply to is _"If the community decides to stop defend such bad quality posts"_. Do you actually think that voting to close a question as unclear (which is likely to end up deleted anyway) is "defending bad quality posts"? Using the right tool for each case is hardly the same as looking the other way. Another example would be downvoting a _wrong_ answer and not flagging it.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed That's fine to disagree, and if users downvote as they don't understand how I wrote/meant with the question, and not _communicate that to me_ so I can adjust, well, do I have to say more...all in a nut shell.

Comment: @LGSon "just disappointing that SO allow such bad quality posts" it doesn't allow them. They are *off-topic*. Have a nice break :)

Comment: Then why is the flag called "very low quality" and not called "unidentifiable garbage"?

Comment: @immibis good question. Might be worth discussing