# Is there a correct way to give feedback to "bad triage" voter (besides flagging for mod attention)?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues

[Giving feedback to inexperienced users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340736/giving-feedback-to-inexperienced-reviewers) gives a specific example, and the only answer there suggests to flag the person doing bad reviews.

Is there really no *correct* other way?

Assume I flag another user X, and even list a few bad votings in the flag request. The mod still has to walk through the voting history to make an informed decision.

On the other hand, the only way for me to contact X is to write a comment below one of his questions/answers. But anybody reading such comments could (rightfully so?!) flag it as `It's no longer needed.` So while this option is possible, is it legit?

One potential way out of that (feature request): assume X reviewed question Q. Wouldn't it be appropriate if I could now use @X when commenting on that question Q? Meaning: X already contributed to Q. So addressing a concern with that contribution on Q that X gets notified about seems pretty reasonable to me. Or am I overlooking something?

Comment: We are allowed to moderate posts, not users. That's the responsibility of moderators. Otherwise we would tear each other apart, drive ourself up to the wall.

Comment: @Braiam It is an essential part of this community that new new users asking low quality questions receive feedback on their post. That feedback still goes to the user. Giving feedback about a review vote, is that *really*, in essence, different from giving feedback on a posting?

Comment: We give feedback *about* the post, not about the user.

Comment: A posting is *observable* behavior. So is a voting decision. If you can decouple a question from the user, why isn't that possible for a voting decision.

Comment: Voting is decoupled from the user, reviews aren't.

Comment: I am talking about users putting comments under output of other users. Sorry, but I don't get what you are trying to communicate with that last statement.

Comment: @GhostCat, I would like to thank you for considering my suggestion and bringing this on the meta. I will follow the discussion with an interest to see what the general opinion is and to try to comply with it. I will also remove my comment, as I think it is no longer needed.

Comment: @GhostCat, I have just read the linked question. It says: _...provide feedback to those users who seem to consistently review counter to the majority opinion._ Your question is asked in general, but because it all started from my review, I would like to mention once again, that it was not _counter to_, but _with_ the majority opinion. I would also like to stress the word _consistently_, citing my (now deleted) comment: _I often go back to the question after casting a vote to check the other opinions and if they are different, I try to understand why in order to improve my reviewing technique_.

Comment: cont.: which means, that I put effort in the process. In short, I am not convinced that I fall into the category of _bad reviews_. However, any suggestion for improvement is very welcome.

Comment: Just to be precise here: my main focus with this question is to clarify whether there are legit ways to approach other users (or if there could be better ways).

Comment: @scopchanov We wouldn't have such discussion if the *majority* is right. The very problem is that the majority of triage reviews that vote EDIT make the wrong decision. Therefore, the absolute majority of items in the "help and improvement" queue do not belong there. The majority of reviewers believes that "edit" means: "you can hit the edit button and fix *something*". And that is simply wrong. Edit means: "anybody can hit the edit button and fix the answer to make it good enough to be answerable". I think that 50-80% on the HI queue are not like that.

Comment: Assume you have 3 to 5 people deciding whether a boat is suited to go on the water. When *you* are the person sitting in the boat on the water ... and it starts sinking, does it matter to you 3, 4, or 5 people said: "the boat is fine it wont sink"? No, it doesn't. Because these other people are happily judging the next boat already, and you are left in the sinking boat. So again: the majority of reviewers votes wrong, in the majority of cases.