# Review audit failed in triage - possibly bad review audit?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits, triage, spam

I was reviewing triage and [came across a post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/26781146) which looked quite decent, and I was actually happy to blow the dust off the <kbd>Looks OK</kbd> button.

But that was a review audit, and one that I failed. The post was flagged as **spam**.

I carefully checked the links and the code, and there's no hints of spam. Is this a bad review audit which is mistakenly in circulation, or did I miss some crucial aspect of the question?

**Edit:** and I'm also suspended from review now...

Adding a couple pics (the post doesn't fit in one screenshot):

[image]
[image]

Comment: I see no problem with the post, probably a troublesome’s user non-troublesome post. A mod should hopefully unsuspend you

Comment: This is definitely a bad audit, but I'd suggest (1) When an answer posts a large [block of code with nearly no explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/26779922), better to ask them in a comment to elaborate a bit in English (2) Don't be afraid to aggressively edit out noise like ["IMHO"](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/26780321) and ["Have a nice day"](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/26780205) and ["Happy Coding"](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/26773146) etc

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Argh, it looks like this is my fault. I nuked that post as spam for reasons of moderation, when I should have nuked it as "rude or abusive". I *know* that, and so I don't know how I missed doing it in this case.

Sorry about that. This was a bad audit.

However, you aren't banned by a single audit, so something else is going wrong with your understanding of how Triage works. Have you read [our guide to Triage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/how-does-the-triage-queue-work)? What other audits have you failed?

Comment: Out of curiosity: what made that post _rude or abusive_?

Comment: @Bill Nothing about the post. It was about the user account that posted it. That's why it's a bad audit. Choosing "rude or abusive" would have kept it from being an audit, which is why I should have done that.

Comment: @CodyGray I failed a couple audits in Triage when I was just starting out, (2 days ban), and failed two more (4 day ban) in Late Answers by choosing no action instead of downvoting. I don't downvote answers that I'm not sure will be deleted bc it's already hard enough to build up rep in my low-traffic tag... And I just got back my review privileges when I failed this audit, so the system banned me again right away... I think I'm doing ok in Triage overall (but you can judge it yourself) and the last ban [taught me](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314679) how to deal with bad answers.

Comment: I'm not talking about previous bans. Those will extend the duration of *this* ban, but a ban is never given for failing a single audit.

Comment: @CodyGray I was banned this time after failing just this one audit. As a mod, you probably can verify this claim. I didn't fail other audits since I got back my privileges last time. In total, since I started reviewing 700 rep ago, I failed 5 audits, 3 in triage and 2 in Late Answers

Comment: @CodyGray anyway, may I ask to have my review privilege restored? Even though I might have made mistakes in the past, it's not fair to be suspended because of what has been recognized as a bad audit.

Comment: That's the point of saying that you aren't ever suspended for failing a single audit. Yes, I could go back through all of your review history, but that takes a lot of time. I was hoping you'd provide me with more information so I didn't have to do that.

Comment: @CodyGray I'd be glad to provide you with more info, but after poking around in meta, I couldn't find a way to filter my failed review audits. As I have more than 1k reviews in triage alone, opening them all one by one is a bit impractical. If you don't want to restore my privilege on the basis of my claim alone, that's fine, I get that. I will just wait my ban out. Thank you

Comment: @CodyGray Users will be suspended for failing a single audit, if they fail it within 30 days of coming off a previous review suspension. Sure, it's not just that one audit failure, but also their previous audit failures which led to the first suspension, that lead to the re-imposed suspension, but that doesn't change the fact that the proximate cause is the single failure. I wouldn't see a problem in lifting such a re-suspension if the audit was clearly bad.