# What exactly happens when an answer is flagged as "Very Low Quality"?

Tags: support, review-queues, flags, low-quality-posts

I've always assumed that when an answer is flagged as "very low quality", it goes to the "Low-Quality Posts" review queue; and that's for two reasons:

1. Because of the name. They both share the "low-quality" aspect, so it makes sense.
2. The text in the review bar (in the LQP queue) usually says:

   > This answer was ***flagged*** as low-quality because of its length and content. <sup>[emphasis mine]</sup>

Well, yesterday, I flagged a bunch of answers as VLQ and two things happened that made me question my previous assumption:

1. I noticed that out of 12 helpful flags, the action (i.e., answer deleted) was taken by a moderator in 11 of them.
2. I got a flag declined (rightfully so) where the moderator message said:

   > Blah blah blah... This does not require moderator intervention.

So, it appears that flagging an answer as VLQ makes it go to the moderators' queue(s) and not [just] to the LQP queue. I tried searching for an answer but I couldn't find anything documented that tells *exactly* what happens when an answer is flagged as VLQ.

Comment: IIRC a VLQ flag will go to the LQPRQ - and after a delay (an hour?) will go to a moderators' queue but they can choose to see what's there before the delay. If the LQPRQ reviewers don't handle the review in time the moderators may handle the flag.

Comment: @WaiHaLee I thought they go to the Low Quality posts review queue as well?

Comment: Related: [How do VLQ flags work, what's their relationship to the LQP queue, what's their *purpose*, and how can the site document them better?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/314679/1364007)

Comment: @WaiHaLee That's a good find. Thanks! I also just found a post on Meta SE that is similar to mine: [Who is handling Very Low Quality flags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/233910/348196). The accepted answer is from 2014. I'm not sure if the rules are still the same.

Comment: Related, includes visual flowchart: [Help us test question triage!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278380/4642212).

Comment: The situation that has resulted in moderators handling your flags is that our cherished moderators have successfully brought their flag queue down. So while the post you flagged is indeed in the Low Quality Posts review queue, once it also gets pushed into the moderator queue, it's handled quite fast. A few months ago, it was more common than not that the posts were fully handled in the Low Quality Posts review queue.