# We finally need more appropriate review actions in Help and Improvement

Tags: discussion, feature-request, help-improvement

First, I am aware of [this Meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287466/help-improve-the-help-improvement-queue). But we haven't heard of any improvements for a long time now.

I think the problem is bigger than ever before. Currently I am skipping 19 out of 20 questions because I cannot take a proper action.

Mostly the content cannot be solved through editing. But [it is not bad enough](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265764) to flag it as VLQ. On the other hand we have questions that should have been given the green light in Triage before.

To clear the queue, we can only use VLQ or Edit (where both actions are inappropriate).

In its current state we do not help anyone. If you skipped your action for the 20th time in a row, you are going to burn out.

If we would be able to throw the question/answer out of the review queue, we would be able to save the next 500 reviewers from one "skip". They would be able to edit a question that actually needs editing instead.

So I suggest that we have the following actions:

- Vote to Close
- Requires no Editing, Looks OK

---

Currently the [skip rate is 83.4 %](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/346054) in the Help & Improvement queue.

---

In some way, [the system, want's that we have more actions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350728/how-to-handle-identified-spam-in-hi) then `[VLQ]` and `[Edit]`

Comment: Your two proposed actions would basically turn H&I back into Triage.  I think that's the right idea, actually; if the triager has to make the edit themselves, they'll actually close questions that require the asker to edit, as closure was intended.  (But I get the impression that the developers gave up on Triage/H&I a while ago.)

Comment: If the question is closed it is removed from the queue. Theres nothing stopping you from visiting the question and voting to close it. Then if you km skip it you will not be shown it again. Who knows, someone else might be able to edit it into shape. There are userscripts that enable voting and close voting in the queues.

Comment: Could the questions with answers be removed automatically from help and improvement queue? The stated goal is to "make questions clear and answerable". If there is an answer already, can we just assume that question got the answer it deserved, and move on?

Comment: There needs to be a delete/unsalvageable button in *every* review queue. Because let's face it, half of the nonsense that gets into review queues is just that. All the other options are silly and a waste of time when what you *really* want to do is make the bad stuff go away.

Comment: The core problem is that this review queue never made much sense to begin with. Neither did triage.

Answer (score 12):

This would turn H&I into the First Posts queue. There, you can upvote, downvote, flag and edit. And "No Action Needed" has the same results as "Looks OK" - voting to remove it from the queue without further ado.

H&I is fed from Triage, and that queue isn't working as intended. We've had a lot of posts about that.

But H&I itself isn't functioning either. When it was first created, it had a high bar - you had to edit a lot and give extensive explanation. At some point, the bar was lowered so that even very small edits were enough to count as a "review". The result shows - lots of superficial edits, and rare indeed is the H&I reviewer who tries to explain to a new user how the site works.

So I say we merge Triage and H&I back into First Posts.

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to just merge Triage and Help and Improvement, so that there would be the actions Looks OK, Edit and Unsalvageable.

Comment: @DonaldDuck Then the difference with First Posts would be that you could use "Looks OK" instead of upvoting/downvoting. I like your idea, but I'm not convinced that it is sufficiently different from First Posts.

Comment: The difference would also be that the posts in First Posts are only first posts and that wouldn't necessarily be the case in Triage.

Answer (score -5):

I don't think that the problem is with Help & Improvement; the problem is with the reviewers.

For example, in Triage, clarify a few things:

- It is *completely okay* to both downvote and review "Looks OK" on the same question.
- "Requires Editing" should **only** be used if a decent edit could be made by **2K users**, not the OP.

---

As for Help & Improvement: I don't view that queue as "the final, hardest Steward badge; the queue where you can only complete 5% of reviews". A lot of my pre-2K time on Stack Overflow was spent trawling through old questions, looking for posts to edit (for my Archaeologist badge) and comments to flag. This seems to have prepared me quite well for the Help & Improvement queue: I can easily spot edits to make from a few seconds of looking at a post, and I have a large arsenal of possible edits to apply. Because of this, I think of Help & Improvement as **a place where questions in need of editing can get attention from good editors.**

Consider looking at [my top Meta answer](/a/338670/6388243) and training yourself to spot some of the edits that I list in it. You might find yourself completing a more reviews in Help & Improvement.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that you would apply an edit just to do anything even though the question would still be unanswerable? If not, then I guess you're missing the point in OPs question.

Comment: @Tom [Excuse me.](https://yourlogicalfallacyis.com/strawman)

Comment: Ok, you didn't understand OPs question, no problem.

Comment: @Tom tell me one thing about the question that I didn't understand.

Comment: OPs question isn't about polishing bad questions and that's all you told us about. OP want to remove bad questions from the queue by voting to close them, as they are unanswerable in the current state, not by editing some spelling mistakes and tags. And something like the proposed "close" button seems appropriate until the "Triage" reviewers learned to do their job correctly (something you understood).

Comment: @Tom but bad questions are *already* removed from the review queue. Otherwise, the review queue would be a *lot* bigger.