# Can we change the link text to Triage queue help?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, triage, user-experience

In the Triage review queue, there is a link at the top left that reads "We need your [help separating questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295674/7292819) into categories."  It's a link to instruction on how Triage reviews should be done.  I spent a couple of months (280 reviews) before I clicked this link.  I saw it every time but really thought it was taking me to do other work.  Let's just say I was not doing all of my reviewing the way this would have me do.

Anyway, can we change this to read "Read this before reviewing from Triage queue" or "Instructions for Triage reviews" or anything my simple mind would find obvious?

Comment: Well, look at this. Another one of those truly reasonable and really easily implementable ideas that can help with the huge issue that is garbage review jobs that are caused by people not knowing how to review in Triage. And because this is such a nice and easy way with a high chance of actually improving things, it's probably going to end up on the same pile as [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321895/change-triage-guidelines-for-requires-editing) where it will gather community upvotes and absolutely no response from developers.

Comment: *and absolutely no response from developers*, that is the part I seriously do not understand, since this is one of the main problems H&I has. What is that difficult?!

Comment: At least this is something that has a chance of being implemented. Anything bigger is unlikely to happen anytime soon as there arent any devs to spare for the review system, and the review system hasn't aged well and is in need of a rewrite.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adopt a consistent policy on what "Requires Editing" means in the review queues](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332546/adopt-a-consistent-policy-on-what-requires-editing-means-in-the-review-queues)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of today, the guidance now reads:

[image: Requires Editing for questions that you can make clear and answerable by editing]

...complete with a second link to [the guide](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/is-there-a-guide-for-the-triage-queue/295674#295674) explicitly identified in the last line in the expanded instructions.

Answer (score 33):

Yes. Anything which makes this more clear is welcome to me.

[image: Yes please]

Especially because [Help & Improvement has seriously problems](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339462/we-finally-need-more-appropriate-review-actions-in-help-and-improvement), because triage reviewers choose the wrong actions.

The worst problem is, the current [quick info encourages wrong review behaviour](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321895/change-triage-guidelines-for-requires-editing), while the question that is linked shows the correct one.

Comment: Thanks for putting the "triage" tag on there.  I wasn't aware of it.