# Require some Close Vote experience before Triage

Tags: discussion, triage, help-improvement

Triage is guilty of making [many wrong decisions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339462/we-finally-need-more-appropriate-review-actions-in-help-and-improvement) regarding the *Requires Editing* Button. Many questions that should have been closed as off topic are sent to Help & Improvement.

Maybe some experience in the Close Vote Queue could help to make better decisions in Triage. We need more Close Voters anyway.

So what do you think about a specific requirement of maybe a Close Vote Silver Badge for doing Triage Reviews?

Comment: That would make the queue a 3K+ rep instead of 500 rep queue.  Also, if they read the guidelines in triage requires editing works for almost anything.

Comment: @NathanOliver maybe it would be better if it's a 3k+ queue. For the second part, yeah that's one of the many problems :)

Comment: Having the Reviewer badge does not mean one is a good reviewer. Maybe we should look at how many helpful flags someone has, instead. Or the ratio of helpful/declined flags.

Comment: I don't see what good it would do to make require experience in the close votes queue to do triage, but it may do some good to require experience in the help and improvement queue to do triage. But a better solution would be to change the help text for Requires Editing to something like "For questions where edits by the others would result in a question that is clear and answerable. Make sure you would be able to edit it yourself if you choose this option". The current help text is plain wrong, the author could edit anything into a good question.

Comment: @DonaldDuck I like the idea of requiring experience with H&I before going to Triage. Unfortunately, many reviews in H&I are just superficial edits. For the best result, H&I should also have a higher bar for what counts as a review: not just edits, but also some hands-on guidance to ease our new users in.

Comment: I think a solution that might work is to make users give a reason why they think a question "requires editing". We already have to give a reason why we think a question is unsalvageable, so why not do the same for a "requires editing" decision? Possible reasons may be "Poor spelling" or "formatting problems" (ie when the code isn't formated with 4 spaces). That way the number of "requires editing" clicks for questions where the OP has to include code or something else might go down. Right now, I'm flagging those as "very low quality" and thus (I think) they get sent back to Triage.