# Why are low quality posts not being accepted as low quality

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

What constitutes a low quality post?

I'm commenting and trying to help on these questions, but they are terrible. I would have been downvoted into oblivion for asking these a few years ago. These questions aren't helpful for future users.

---

**Examples**

[How can I use input in Jupyter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57936907/how-can-i-use-input-in-jupyter)

[How to setup Keras environment for macOS for Kaggle dogs-vs-cats task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57937487/how-to-setup-keras-environment-for-macos-for-kaggle-dogs-vs-cats-task)

[Returning list in for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57937204/returning-list-in-for-loop)

---

**Denied**
Not one was accepted.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For information on the use of the low quality flag see

[Am I misusing the "Very Low Quality" flag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265573/am-i-misusing-the-very-low-quality-flag)

As to these particular questions:

The first of these needs to be flagged/closed as a typo. It's a trivial mistake.

The second should be flagged/closed as "too broad" or, also valid, would be off-topic because an off-site resource (tutorial) is requested.

For the third, it's unclear why you'd provide an answer if you think the question is terrible and should not be answered. That question, however, does provide all necessary information to be answered so is not "low quality". It might well be a *duplicate* of something already on the site and in that case would be flagged/closed as such.

Furthermore, I see no point in you providing an answer that really just repeats what someone else wrote as an answer an hour earlier - that's just noise.

Comment: I dont get it. It seems like you agree with me that all of these are of poor quality in some way and should be closed.

Comment: Ask me that again after you've read the information in the link if you still need to... It's a question of what kind of content -> the manner in which it is handeld.

Comment: @HashRocketSyntax the  VLQ flag means: please, delete this, it’s garbage and it’s so bad I can’t even figure out if there’s a question in there! Posts that should be closed should just be closed. Flag them as off-topic, and perhaps down-vote them. The VLQ flag is not a super close-vote or super down-vote!