# Does images of code denote a low quality question?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, low-quality-posts

I’m confused, I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68383853/692942) as Low Quality but my flag has been declined by a moderator? The first image link is to a large block of code which in my opinion is no use to anyone.

If this doesn’t denote a low quality question what does?

According to [this meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265573/am-i-misusing-the-very-low-quality-flag) it does, so why was my flag declined?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Am I misusing the "Very Low Quality" flag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265573/am-i-misusing-the-very-low-quality-flag)

Comment: Vote to close as "needs details or clarity" or "debugging details" instead. Closing is enough, no necessity to get moderators involved.

Comment: @BDL sorry typing on my mobile, forgot the link. Added now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) - *"Questions that contain no code—only images—are generally __closed for lacking debugging details__. Once they are edited to include a minimal, reproducible example in plain text form, __they can be re-opened__."*

Comment: The question isn't bad enough to require deletion as fast as possible. Simply vote to close and downvote. Also: Whenever I read a complaint about a declined flag on meta and then notice that the post has no downvotes, I'm wondering a little bit. If a post is not bad enough to be downvoted, then it's for sure not bad enough to flag.

Comment: @JeanneDark that doesn’t explain why I now have a declined flag against my profile.

Comment: The mod handling the flag wanted to let you know that flagging that question as VLQ was wrong. That's why they declined your flag.

Comment: @JeanneDark why was it wrong is what I’m asking, it’s low quality by your own admission (your dup target) so why should I be penalised?

Comment: You know what. Let's not tell anybody you got a declined flag because that number isn't public. If no one knows, nothing is held against your profile.

Comment: @rene that’s not really the point though is it? Why decline it in the first place when all I did was follow the guidance on meta for what is "Low Quality"?

Comment: @Gimby you expect an editor to interpret that block of code in the image into text without introducing mistakes?

Comment: I can read and understand the text of that question you flagged perfectly fine (it seems English to me) and the images are clear and related to the topic at hand as well. How is it garbage?

Comment: The question is not VLQ. Think of the VLQ flag for questions as a softer R/A flag. The question you flagged as VLQ is neither gibberish ("jgkgksgldksgklgslkgskdlgsdjkgsdskdjg") nor an abusive rant. It's a question that needs debugging details (or details or clarity) and should be closed. That can be handled by the community. No need to involve moderators by flagging it as VLQ.

Comment: @JeanneDark I thought Low Quality questions went into the queue to be reviewed, I didn’t realise they are only handled by mods. I take your point, thanks for explaining.

Comment: @rene you edit it then. Sorry but i’m happy to edit a question fix code block formatting etc but not write out an OPs code from an image verbatim.

Comment: The VLQ flag for question is an endless source of confusion so it's best to simply avoid it. For answers it is better defined (eg. I flag link-only or non-English answers as VLQ), but I've never flagged a question as VLQ.

Comment: One thing that I'm still trying to figure out is why there's no Close review on the timeline. Instead, there's an invalidated Triage review after the question got closed by regular 3 close votes.

Comment: @user692942 no, we expect the OP to edit and add their code in (assuming they want their question to be reopened).

Comment: @AndrewT. I think that’s because as Jeanne said it goes straight to the mods not into review. Which is something I didn’t realise as the timeline was the first thing I checked.

Comment: For sure, no one expects you to write out OP's code from an image verbatim. That's why such questions should be closed - to give the OP time to do it themselves or have it Roomba eventually.

Comment: Anyway, I guess the lesson is that if you already have enough rep for close votes, just vote to close instead of flagging the question, unless it's a spam/rude/need mod...

Comment: You don't paint your house with a hammer. Use the right moderation tools: We have a perfectly fine close reason to handle that type of questions. The OP can edit their post and if they do it goes to the re-open queue. If we delete it they have a hard time editing.

Comment: @rene completely agree, problem was I didn't realise I was using a hammer at the time. Lesson learned. So that [dup target](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265573/am-i-misusing-the-very-low-quality-flag) is very relevant.

Comment: @user692942 What no one appears to have mentioned here is that the VLQ flag is *just broken*, and you should avoid using it outright except in very specific cases. It's annoying, there's been ample discussion about it, and yet still nothing has come of it. It's a mod-handled flag that doesn't give indication of that, its purpose is ambiguous to users, and it's handled inconsistently by moderators across the board. Shake off the declined flag, and just use another one next time; you fell into a trap that you basically had no way to avoid anyways, no harm done.