# Should I flag questions which answer themselves as "Very low quality"?

Tags: discussion, flags, low-quality-posts

Case: [sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: books.id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77257276/sqlite3-integrityerror-unique-constraint-failed-books-id)

Copy-paste in case it's deleted:

> ```
> db = sqlite3.connect("books-collection.db")
> cursor = db.cursor()
> # cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE books (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title varchar(250) NOT NULL UNIQUE, author varchar(250) NOT NULL, rating FLOAT NOT NULL)")
> cursor.execute("INSERT INTO books VALUES(1, 'Harry Potter', 'J. K. Rowling', '9.3')")
> db.commit()
> ```
>
> I got this error
>
> ```
> cursor.execute("INSERT INTO books VALUES(1, 'Harry Potter', 'J. K. Rowling', '9.3')")
> sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: books.id
> ```
>
> how to fix this error ??

The error message is very clear, and there's already a record with that ID, so no insert is made.

Is there any action to be taken in these situations where the only possible answer to give is already in the question's error message? Flag? Reiterate the answer?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265573/am-i-misusing-the-very-low-quality-flag

Comment: The fact that *UNIQUE constraint failed* means that there is an existing item with the same Id might be obvious when you have some experience, but for a beginner that might not be the case. We don't close or flag questions because they are too simple.

Comment: I don't see how this answers itself. I would VTC as needing details since it's not clear what they would want to "fix this error" - remove the constraint, filter the input, keep the old item, update the item, ...

Comment: Do note that when the error is as common as the one in that question, you are very likely to find suitable duplicates. (As already pointed out by others VLQ is not the proper flag to raise)

Comment: You should never flag questions as very low quality.

Comment: I tend to go for "Unclear" too if just parroting the error message is a decent, specific answer, since it's unclear what the OP expects an answer to be if that error message didn't suffice. Arguably, here, an answer could provide some explanation about "An unique ID is unique, you already have a record with an ID", so I'd probably look for a duplicate.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### We don't care if problems are easy to solve

We do care about understanding **why** OP was unable to solve the problem - because that points more clearly at **what the question actually is**.

For common error messages, **try to find a duplicate first**, of course. (Do keep in mind that some error messages can conceptually have many different causes, so this can take more searching than you'd expect.)

Someone who doesn't understand what words like "unique" mean has a question about English, not a question about programming.

On the other hand, someone who wants to know why attempting to insert the value again causes an error instead of the insertion being silently dropped, may have a legitimate question about the design of SQL - if that question is actually highlighted and explicitly asked.

There are many other possibilities between those two ends of the spectrum.

A question like this is low quality, **but not** because you find the error message self-evident.

**Please do not use the "very low quality" flag** for things like this. That is for questions that are literally incomprehensible word salad or it looks like someone's cat walked on the keyboard, etc. That is, things that **couldn't be fixed by any plausible combination of** other people editing the post and OP supplying new information in response to comment feedback.

If there is specific information you think OP can provide that would clarify the question, people with at least 50 reputation should **use the comments** to ask for it. Otherwise, people with at least 15 reputation can **flag as "Needs Improvement"**, and then choose from the standard reasons to close a question. This allows people with close-vote privileges to review the question (especially ones who have subject-matter expertise), rather than pushing the job onto the site's very small, overworked team of moderators.

Comment: Re *"incomprehensible word salad or it looks like someone's cat walked on the keyboard"*: Or the result of [machine translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Translate) (in many cases).

Comment: "Word salad or complete gibberish" would probably cover all bases. Otherwise I would also request adding banging a head on the keyboard to the list of possible causes.